# Couldn't get email from facebook when user accept the email permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook Graph API to get user's email as user account in my system.

It works well 99.9% when user accept the email permission.

But in some accounts, I got 'null' even when user accept the email permission.

and I checked the setting of one account, nothing unusual or different from others.

Do anyone knows what's happened and how to solve it?

many thanks,

Phil

Comment: Is the email property null or is the whole user object null?

Comment: I can get uid, name, birthday..these data, but email can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some users simply won't have an email - it's possible to sign up for Facebook with a cell phone only - if there's some other reason i'm not aware of it, it could be a bug with the API

Comment: I didn't know you can sign up without an email. Can you point me to where I can sign up without one? All the sign up forms I see require an email.

Comment: It's possible via cell phone as far as I know, and definitely was in the past

Comment: I can't see how that can be possible.  How will a user log in without an email address?

Comment: via a cell phone - like I said, it's rare, but possible

Comment: As far as I can tell, even with a cell phone, you still need an email address to log in. Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks for all your comments, but the problem is this user's email were showed on the permission page and he accepted the permission in front of me... does anyone has same problem?

Comment: I just checked, and I also had an instance at the end of January where the user's email was null, even though email permission was accepted.  It doesn't affect my app all that much, because it works fine without email, but this behavior is strange. Did you file a bug with Facebook?